# Hiding URL endpoint in a Angular Application

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am having a use case where we are having an Angular Application -

1. The endpoint of displayed URL in the address bar is like -

> example.com/dashboard/userRole

Where userRole can be of more than 2 types.

2. What I want to achieve is only the domain name should be displayed on the address bar, endpoint like userRole, dashboard should not be visible.
3. Tried using skipLocationChange strategy in routing but whenever user refreshes the page it takes back to the root component i.e, LoginComponent.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: How exactly should the browser know where to take you, when reloading the page?
The only option from my point of view is using localStorage to store URL and reinitialize this URL on application start (using skipLocationChange). Nevertheless this is not a recommended approach. The state of the application should be reflected in the URL. Why hide this information?

Comment: I am assuming that you want to prevent user from going to url which is for another user role, for that you need to implement route guard.

Comment: Like for multiple users we don't want to show like, dashboard/superAdmin, or dashboard/admin, dashboard/user, instead just dashboard or nothing else.

Comment: @AmitKumar yes we are already using route guard but we don't want user to see these details like role etc.

Comment: Best you can do is use random alphanumeric string for different routes. In this way user will see url but won't be able to infer any meaning out of it.

Comment: Please explain your use case, instead of asking for what you think is the solution. [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)